# What might be wrong with my Android installation in Ubuntu 9.04

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm following the installation tutorial according (www.softwarepassion.com/?p=176) to the explanations and everything seems to be fine and not getting any errors. But, when I run the 'Hello, world' application, I get an empty screen on my phone showing me only 'Android' with a blinking cursor. Does anyone know what I might be missing or doing wrong? I'm using eclipse on Ubuntu 9.04.

Here's an screenshot of the emulator when I run the app: www.twitpic.com/5rrcg and here is the screen I should be getting: developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/images/hello_world_5.png

Comment: You dont have to close the emulator for every run. Once the emulator starts, you can run the project again without closing.

Answer (score 2):

How long are you letting it sit at that screen?  The emulator takes a few seconds to load, around 10-15 seconds on my machine.

Comment: yes, after a while the Android logo shows up and then an screen that says 'Android [the actual time] screen locked'

Comment: Sorry... in worked actually. It took a long while. I have to see why it takes so long.